# Можно ли реализовать бокову панель как на сайте карт яндекса?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли реализовать бокову панель как на сайте карт яндекса? ( с фото дома, организациями, как проехать и тд) через API яндекс карт у себя на сайте? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это есть в документации https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметили в комментарии, технически реализовать боковую панель средствами API возможно. [Пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/sidebar/) есть в песочнице.

Но конкретно такой внешний вид вам воссоздавать придётся уже самостоятельно. И использованные стили (цвета, отступы и пр.) вам придётся подбирать уже самостоятельно - Яндекс не публикует эти данные в открытом доступе.

Comment: А для API 3.0 нет примера :(